# Convert English into SQL in NLTK

Tags: sql, nltk

I'm still new on how to Convert English into SQL. I already have seen the two examples in NLTK's grammar: `sql.fcfg` and `sql0.fcfg`.

Is there a more general open source grammar that I can manipulate and edit to build my work on?

By more general I mean that it accepts a wider range of English queries (questions) to be converted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't think of a single instance where I would not prefer to convert prose to code manually.

Comment: Hello @DanBracuk, Thanks for ur reply, If I want to write the grammar manually, then what resources do recommend for me? because I started to write a 'what is' class but I wasn't experienced with such rules so I did stop!

Comment: Write the grammar manually?  Your question suggests that the grammar has already been written.

Comment: @DanBracuk yes there is a number of small grammars have been written but they are very restricted to cover a small amount of English sentences, but what I'm looking for is something more general -if there is any!-. Thanks

Comment: I meant by 'Write the grammar manually' convert the English questions into rules, not by any mean that I already have the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Covington's books

- NLP for Prloog Programmers (1994)
- Prolog Programming in Depth (1997)

Will help You go a long way. These books are available free from his [site](http://www.covingtoninnovations.com/books.html).